# How to update a date field from another date field value?

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button

I'm trying to update a date field after a button press. The source value is from another date field on the same VF page.

```
        var newRecords = []; 
        var c = new sforce.SObject("Service_Order__c"); 
        c.id ="{!Service_Order__c.Id}"; 
        c.Payment_1_Invoice__c = {!Service_Order__c.Invoice_Ref_1__c};
        c.Invoice_Date_1__c = {!Service_Order__c.Scheduled_Payment_Date_1__c}; 
        newRecords.push(c); 
        result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);          
        window.location.reload();
```

But the {!Service_Order__c.Scheduled_Payment_Date_1__c} value gives me this error:

```
faultstring:''0.009915716410510659' is not a valid value for the type xsd:date'
```

Tried using the value of {!Service_Order__c.Scheduled_Payment_Date_1__c} with "" and it gives me this error:

```
faultstring:''2/1/2017' is not a valid value for the type xsd:date'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `new Date().toISOString()` to correct date format conversion.

> Here use, `new Date(parameter).toISOString()`

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 
var newRecords = []; 
var c = new sforce.SObject("Service_Order__c"); 
c.id ="{!Service_Order__c.Id}"; 

c.Payment_1_Invoice__c = new Date("{!Service_Order__c.Invoice_Ref_1__c}").toISOString(); 
c.Invoice_Date_1__c = new Date("{!Service_Order__c.Scheduled_Payment_Date_1__c}").toISOString(); 

newRecords.push(c); 
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Thanks Santanu! Works like a gem! Now I need to figure out why "2/1/2017" converts to "1/31/2017" when using the solution above.

Comment: Can you please close this question

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation points to close this question. But did mark you answer as accepted. Thanks!